# Target CSS class and ref="label"

Tags: css

I am using an install of formIO survey builder.

If I disable a `text-area` in the form builder I can grey out the disabled text on the front-end with the following CSS

```
.formio-component-textarea div.formio-editor-read-only-content[ref=input] {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #e5e6e7;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

I want to grey out the labels for disabled text-area components as well.

from the Chrome inspection tool for a single disabled text area, I get

`<label id="l-edd23g6-19b853750c2b43cc992536b1e" for="edd23g6-19b853750c2b43cc992536b1e" class="col-form-label" ref="label">Text Area</label>`

Is it possible to apply this class `.formio-component-textarea div.formio-editor-read-only-content[ref=input]`

to `ref="label"` to achieve this?

Comment: You can have more than one selector to css definition, just add `[ref=label]` as second selector, for ex.: `.formio-component-textarea div.formio-editor-read-only-content[ref=input], .formio-component-textarea label[ref=label]`